How to set the id in JsonApi when updating
I am trying to make update/PATCH request using Jsonapi: https://jsonapi.org/format/
export const update = (type: string, id: string, body: object = {}, query: object = {}) => {
    const bodyTemp = { data: { id, type, ...body } };
    return jsonApi.update(type, bodyTemp, query);
};

The error in this code is, it is not getting the id probably because jsonApi has a setup that I couldnt figure out what.
the url is getting like this: http://localhost/api/url instead it should be like this http://localhost/api/url/${id}
How can I fix it?

This question seems to be related to a specific implementation of the JSON:API specification. Without knowing the concrete implementation, it is nearly impossible to help you.
